# The system cannot find the path specified. Unable to start Zookeeper

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I installed Kafka in my C directory and then

1. `cd bin\windows`.
2. `zookeeper-server-start.bat ..\..\config\zookeeper.properties`

Error is "The system cannot find the path specified." I tried Everything. How to correct it.